# Getting the URI of a file when an ACTION_SEND Intent is generated

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bluetooth

I want to create an Android app which can send files via bluetooth and want my app to work on the ACTION_SEND intent whenever that appears. In this case, how can I actually get the URI of the file that is to be transferred into my mainActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `getIntent().getData()` in `onCreate()` to get the `Uri` supplied in the `Intent` that was used to create your activity.

If you are using an `android:launchMode` that may cause an existing instance of your activity to be brought back to the foreground, you will also need to override `onNewIntent()` to be informed when this occurs. You can call `getData()` on the `Intent` supplied to `onNewIntent()` to get the `Uri`.